# Detecting Words mistakes in String Input

Tags: java, string, swing

I am trying to make a code that can detect mistakes in the user input with respect to String array stored in program.

Lets say Program contains "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

if the user enters "The quick brown is name over Jumps the lazy"

The program tells the user that you have made 5 Mistakes. But my code is not working correctly for the above mentioned user input. What is my code lacking to detect such mistakes. Here is the code:

```
public void checkTextCompleted()
{
    String input= text.getText();
    int temp=array[0],mistakes=0;

    if(input.length()==data.length()) {
        text.setEditable(false);
        text.setFocusable(false);

        for(int j=0;j<dataWords;j++) {
            int x = input.indexOf(data.substring(array[j]-temp, array[j]-1));

            System.out.println(x);
            if(x != -1) {
                String subs = input.substring(x, input.length());

                if(data.contains(subs)) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    mistakes++;
                    if(j!=0)
                        temp=array[j-1];
                    else
                        temp=array[j];
                }
            }
            else
                mistakes++;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have made "+mistakes+" mistakes" , "Typing Test Completed", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
    }
}
```

The array[] contains the positions at which the space is detected in Program builtin String(data) and dataWords contains the number of words in program builtin String(data). User input is stored in "input"

What is my code lacking to detect the above mentioned problem?

**Note:**
if one word is wrong and the remaining string after it is correct, mistake will be 1 other wise, next mistake will be detected on the same principal.

[image]

Regards

Comment: When is something 1 mistake? What are your requirements? E.g. 'a b' instead of ' ba', is this 1 or 2 mistakes? 'abc' instead of 'cba'; 1 or 3 mistakes?

Comment: What are you actually trying to ask ?

Comment: 1 mistake occurs when the user inputs "The QUick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" or "The qui brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". Similarly 2 mistakes occur when input is "The QUik brown fox jmps over the lazy dog". In nut shall before declaring a mistake, my program checks the substring after the word, whose index is find currently

Comment: so you will have at most one mistake per word?

Comment: yes but rest of the input string after the mistaken word should match with the Builtin string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant you shrink your code by this simple logic ?

```
String[] expectedSentenceA = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".split(" ");
String[] inputStringA = inputString.split(" ");
int diff=  expectedSentenceA.length-inputStringA.length;
if(diff>0) {
    System.out.println("You have missed " + diff + " word(s)..!!!");
} else if (diff < 0) {
    System.out.println("Found " + diff + " excess word(s)..!!!");
}else {
   ArrayList<String> mistakeWords= new ArrayList();
   for(int i=0;i<expectedSentenceA.length;i++) {
    if(!expectedSentenceA[i].equals(inputStringA[i])){
        mistakeWords.add(inputStringA[i]);
    }
   }
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total Mistakes ["+mistakeWords.size()+"] are " + mistakeWords);
}
```

Comment: Must check size of inputStringA before compare

Comment: Thanks you showed me a new way to work with string. Thanks alot for your help

Comment: Good experiment. Try more. Here is a game example which I did using swing [Java Swing Shuffle Game](http://javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-swing-shuffle-game)

Comment: what if the length of the input string is less then builtin string? I am thinking to set a condition if input string length is less than builtin string lenght, then checking loop will run until the length of input string. Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all of your code, but what's wrong with a solution like this:

```
String[] expectedWords = "The quick brown fox".split(" ");
String[] inputWords = inputText.split(" ");
int mistakes = 0;
if (expectedWords.length != inputWords.length) {
    return;
}
for (int i = 0; i < expectedWords.length; i++) {
    if (!expectedWords[i].equals(inputWords[i])) {
        mistakes++;
    }
}
// Show number of mistakes.
```

Comment: you are checking the Strings character by character which may declare wrong number of mistakes.

Comment: Not character by character, word by word!

Comment: Or I don't understand your question. Entering `The FOO brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` would result in 1 error, if the array elements were one word each.

Comment: actually you are considering String as char array. Your code checks whether the input string array is equal to Builtin String array.

Comment: Should this `The FOO brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` result in 1 mistake? - Than my code is correct. Otherwise I do not understand your requirements.

Comment: yes. I mentioned the principal on which mistake counter is incremented in my question